# Small text in table does not recalculate line spacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, fontsize, line-spacing

I'm using `tabu` to create a table that has a couple multi-line cells (the `m` style). However, when I set the line spacing outside the table, it seems that the space between lines is not recalculated in the table, and when I make the font small, the spacing is too large:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu} 

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|}
    {\scriptsize Line 1 \linebreak too much space here} &
    {\Huge Title} &
    Right side \linebreak Line 1 \linebreak and line 2
\end{tabu}

A normal paragraph: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

Putting another `\linespread` inside the table doesn't change anything. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you need to add a `\par` at the end. You can see the same effect outside of tabular it you enclose the last paragraph in a `{}`, and change the `\linespread` inside it.  Unless there is a `\par` the changes inside won't have any effect.

Comment: @PeterGrill Forgot to mention in my question but I tried that, and it works, but it adds an extra space after the text (which is undesirable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line spacing is set at the end of the paragraph. If the text is put into group braces, before the end of the paragraph is reached, then the line spacing before the group is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|}
    \scriptsize Line 1 \linebreak too much space here &
    \Huge Title &
    Right side \linebreak Line 1 \linebreak and line 2
\end{tabu}

A normal paragraph: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or with `\linespread{1}` inside the table cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|}
    \linespread{1}\selectfont
    \scriptsize Line 1 \linebreak too much space here &
    \Huge Title &
    \linespread{1}\selectfont
    Right side \linebreak Line 1 \linebreak and line 2
\end{tabu}

A normal paragraph: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, this works great! It made me realize that I didn't even want to change the `linespread` in my table, I just needed to remove the `{}`.